# error while importing tables to another database

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

I used expdp to export data from one oracle database 'XXX' to user oracleabc. While importing it to another database in completely different oracle server ie, user is different.'oracleabc', Im getting this error.
ORA-01918: user 'XXX' does not exist

code used:

```
 impdp oracleabc/oracleabc@ora REMAP_TABLE=XXX:oracleabc directory=dir333 dumpfile=TRADE_DATABASE.dmp logfile=TRADE_EXP.log
```

It seems like the new database is trying to access tables from dump file like this. "XXX".table_name.While Im trying to import it to user oracleabc. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. use REMAP_SCHEMA and not REMAP_TABLE